# How to show instante change on like and unlike button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on reactjs project which has like and dislike button and if the Button is liked or disliked is also checked by api. But the problem is to see the changes U have to refresh page. I am using react with redux for state management. Any help would be great.These are my codes.

> actions.

```
export const likeShop = (shopId) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_LOAD
    });
    new _rest().put(`/buyer/shop/${shopId}/like`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('like shop', res);
            dispatch({
                type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_SUCCESS,
                payload: res
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({
                type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_ERROR,
                error: err
            })
    })
}
export const unLikeShop = (shopId) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_UNLIKE_LOAD
    });
    new _rest().delete(`/buyer/shop/${shopId}/like`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('like shop', res);
            dispatch({
                type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_UNLIKE_SUCCESS,
                payload: res
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
            type: shopActionTypes.SHOP_UNLIKE_ERROR,
            error: err
        })
    })
}
```

> reducers

```
export default (state={}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_LOAD:
        case shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            };
        case shopActionTypes.SHOP_LIKE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.error
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

> component

```
const shopLike = () => {
      if(isLiked.shop !== null &&  isLiked.shop === true) {
        this.props.unLikeShop(dataProduct.details.vendorId)
      }else if(isLiked.shop !== null && isLiked.shop === false) {
        this.props.likeShop(dataProduct.details.vendorId);
      }
    }

 <BottomNavigationAction
            onClick={shopLike}
            label="Shop"
            value="Shop"
            icon={
              isLiked && isLiked.shop ===true ? <StoreIcon style={{color:'red'}}/>:
                  <StoreIcon/>
            }
          />
```

> fetting state

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userTypeDetails: state.userType,
    userData: state.user.data.currentUser,
    dataProduct: state.productDetails.data,
    ui: state.productDetails.ui,
    isLiked: state.addToCart.isItemInCart,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  openTeamDrawer,
  likeProduct,
  unLikeProduct,
  likeShop,
  unLikeShop
};
```

Here `isLiked` is coming from redux store. and there is one more reducer for check like which returns if the shop is liked of not in boolean value.

Comment: Instead of rendering conditionally `StoreIcon` pass down to it `isLiked` as prop, and check internally to update style.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the code you posted, if the toggle like request takes a long time then there is a delay but nothing that would require a reload. You can check the redux devtools to see if the actions are dispatched correctly and state is adjusted accordingly. If you don't want a delay then you can reduce on `SHOP_LIKE_LOAD` assuming that toggle is successful and has no errors. How do you get the like state, are you using mapStateToProps or useSelector and can you post that?

Comment: Could you post all the code of the component? Just to check that Connect HOC is used properly

Comment: @HMR I have updated my question and added the `HOC` code

Comment: The fact that you have `state.addToCart.isItemInCart.shop` as true or false looks a bit wonky but if that was wrong then why would it show in a reload? Unless you set it with other data when you load then when you click on like. Best inspect the redux def tools to see what that data is on load and on like/dislike